# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

Where can I find information on the candidates for the ServerFault and other elections?

Comment: That page loads but that's about it for me. Clicking the icons does nothing. Down the bottom there are just a bunch of "Loading... " messages but no activity.

Comment: That page seems to be somewhat broken in any browser except for IE when I try view it.

Comment: @John - you'd have to post a message on MSO or chat for Yi Jiang. I'm only passing the information along.

Comment: @Zoredache - you'd have to post a message on MSO or chat for Yi Jiang. I'm only passing the information along.

Comment: Given that this has been edited out of all recognition, as well as no longer being relevant, I thing it should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://elections.stackexchange.com/).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)